# Error when retrieving data from mysql in json format by the server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, express

I connected the sql to the project, everything works fine, but when I try to retrieve the data and return the information in json format, I get an error

controllers

```
        const {connection} = require('../../dbConected')
        module.exports = {
            getallstudents:(req, res) => {
               const select = connection.query("SELECT * FROM student")
               let json_select = JSON.stringify(select)
                    res.status(200).json({
                        json_select
                    }).catch(error => {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        error
                    })
                })
            }
        }
```

sql connection

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            password: "my password",
            database: "test"
        });
        connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err
                console.log("connection");
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM test.student",function (err,result){
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(result);
                })
        })
        module.exports = { connection }
```

routes

```
const express = require("express");
const {connection} = require('../../dbConected')
const router = express.Router();

const {
    getallstudents
} = require('../controllers/student')
router.get("/", getallstudents)

module.exports = router;
```

the err

"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Query'\n    |     property '_timer' -> object with constructor 'Timer'\n    --- property '_object' closes the circle"

and

```
GET /getallstudents 500 4.448 ms - 224
```

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: `connection.query()` doesn't return the results. You have to provide a callback function, and it receives the results as an argument. There's also a promise-based version that returns a promise; you use `await` or `.then()` to get the results.

Comment: You should be able to find examples in a tutorial on node-mysql.